# Firefox numeric textbox validation code not working

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I have written the following code to validate the textbox with numbers with only two digits after decimal but it is not working in firefox
it blocks all keys after we have typed two digits after decimal.
Exampls: if i type 123.45 i cannot perform any other event the textbox acts like it is disabled.

Javascript:

function noAlphabets(event) {

```
var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode
if (charCode == 188) {
    return true;
}
//Compatible with IE8 & other browser
var obj = event.currentTarget ? event.currentTarget : event.srcElement;
var newvalue = $(obj).val();
alert(newvalue);// $(event.currentTarget).val();
//if (newvalue.indexOf(".") >= 0) {
//    if (newvalue.substr(newvalue.indexOf(".") + 1, (newvalue.length - 1)).length >= 2)
//    { return false; }
//}
if ((charCode != 46 && charCode > 31
        && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
         || (charCode == 46 && $(obj).val().indexOf(".") != -1))
    return false;

return true;
```

}

MVC view code:

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FolioList[i].Amount, (Model.FolioList[i].IsFolioChecked) ? (object)new { @onkeypress = "return noAlphabets(event);" } : (object)new { disabled = "disabled", @onkeypress = "return noAlphabets(event);" })

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're looking to make it so that you can change the value of the box (i.e. use backspace to erase the input and be able to enter a new value). With that in mind, here's the solution I devised. This checks whether there is a period in the box, then checks to see if the length of the substring after the period is larger than 2. If it is larger than 2 and the keycode of the most recent keypress is not backspace, then prevent that keypress. The second if statement checks to see if the key is not a number, backspace, or a period. If it isn't any of those, then prevent the keypress.

```
$("#validate").keydown(function(e){
    var pressedKey = (e.which || e.keycode);
    if (e.target.value.indexOf('.') > -1 && e.target.value.substr(e.target.value.indexOf('.')).length > 2 && pressedKey != 8) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    if (((pressedKey < 48 || pressedKey > 57) && (pressedKey < 96 || pressedKey > 105)) && pressedKey != 8 && pressedKey != 190) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/IronFlare/7xpLhhxa/1/

Comment: The script take more than two values after decima and also multiple decimals. and also not working in firefox.

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly, then you're looking for it to just set a variable (i.e something would return true) if there are no more than two characters between each period or between a period and the end of the input. Is this correct?

Comment: @NIMESHJAIN This is a very late reply, but I just re-read your comment and I think I now understand what you meant. I created the initial prototype on an old browser which didn't understand the input type "Number". As a result, the script worked correctly there and didn't when it was run on an updated browser. I changed the input type to "Text" and that fixed the problem ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7xpLhhxa/3/)). Feel free to let me know if this works or if this isn't what you're looking for.